# gateway migration services working locally but not remotely

Tags: networking, dns, gateway

I have been tasked to migrate a gateway server "debian 8.1" from a physical server to a VM using CloneZilla.

After running the VM, the VM was working fine and all I have changed is the network card name in:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

Then network works fine and connect using SSH.

The problem is, services like apache2, svn, bind9 ... etc are working fine "LOCALLY"... but when trying to check these service remotely they are not working.

Example of checking services remotely:

`[~]>telnet 192.168.1.1 80` `Trying 192.168.1.1...`

`[~]>telnet 192.168.1.1 443` `Trying 192.168.1.1...`

`[~]>nslookup google.com 192.168.1.1` `;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iptables caused the problem by it's rules, I have changed the eth names and it's worked fine.